Installing glpk to work with it in Visual Studio Code
I need to write C++ code using GLPK. I installed the required package in the MSYS2 terminal via the command:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glpk

However, when I try to use the methods from this package at code, I get a message that an error has occurred, but no errors were found.
Here's the code itself:
#include <glpk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    glp_prob *lp;
    int ia[1+1000], ja[1+1000];
    double ar[1+1000], z, x1, x2, x3;
    lp = glp_create_prob();
    glp_set_prob_name(lp, "sample");
    glp_set_obj_dir(lp, GLP_MAX);
    glp_add_rows(lp, 3);
    glp_set_row_name(lp, 1, "p");
    glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 1, GLP_UP, 0.0, 100.0);
    glp_set_row_name(lp, 2, "q");
    glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 2, GLP_UP, 0.0, 600.0);
    glp_set_row_name(lp, 3, "r");
    glp_set_row_bnds(lp, 3, GLP_UP, 0.0, 300.0);
    glp_add_cols(lp, 3);
    glp_set_col_name(lp, 1, "x1");
    glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 1, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
    glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 1, 10.0);
    glp_set_col_name(lp, 2, "x2");
    glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 2, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
    glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 2, 6.0);
    glp_set_col_name(lp, 3, "x3");
    glp_set_col_bnds(lp, 3, GLP_LO, 0.0, 0.0);
    glp_set_obj_coef(lp, 3, 4.0);
    ia[1] = 1, ja[1] = 1, ar[1] = 1.0; /* a[1,1] = 1 */
    ia[2] = 1, ja[2] = 2, ar[2] = 1.0; /* a[1,2] = 1 */
    ia[3] = 1, ja[3] = 3, ar[3] = 1.0; /* a[1,3] = 1 */
    ia[4] = 2, ja[4] = 1, ar[4] = 10.0; /* a[2,1] = 10 */
    ia[5] = 3, ja[5] = 1, ar[5] = 2.0; /* a[3,1] = 2 */
    ia[6] = 2, ja[6] = 2, ar[6] = 4.0; /* a[2,2] = 4 */
    ia[7] = 3, ja[7] = 2, ar[7] = 2.0; /* a[3,2] = 2 */
    ia[8] = 2, ja[8] = 3, ar[8] = 5.0; /* a[2,3] = 5 */
    ia[9] = 3, ja[9] = 3, ar[9] = 6.0; /* a[3,3] = 6 */
    glp_load_matrix(lp, 9, ia, ja, ar);
    glp_simplex(lp, NULL);
    z = glp_get_obj_val(lp);
    x1 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 1);
    x2 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 2);
    x3 = glp_get_col_prim(lp, 3);
    printf("\nz = %g; x1 = %g; x2 = %g; x3 = %g\n", z, x1, x2, x3);
    glp_delete_prob(lp);
    return 0;
}

I also tried to write the full path to the file in the first line:
#include "C:\msys64\mingw64\include\glpk.h"

But that didn't help either
Massage about error:
enter image description here
enter image description here

"get a message that an error has occurred, but no errors were found" What exactly gives you this error? The program when you run it? Can you add the full error text to the question (or if it's a messagebox where you can't copy text, add a screenshot).

I add 2 images at the end of my question

The actual error message (if any) will be in the terminal at the bottom. From the first glance, it looks it like an incorrect tasks.json configuration (you specified a .cpp file instead of the compiler name).
